# Get GPS without alert view with ROOT permission(jailbreak)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gps, jailbreak

how can i get gps without alert view (jailbroken iphone) ?

```
NSString *newText;

CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

CLLocation* location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Your Position : %f %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];

NSLog(@"%@", newText);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write a program that grabs a user's location without their permission...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[CLLocationManager setAuthorizationStatus:YES forBundleIdentifier:@"your app bundle identifier"];
```

To use this your application entitlements should have `com.apple.locationd.authorizeapplications` key with boolean value set to true.

**UPDATE**

Found much better solution. Add to your application entitlements `com.apple.locationd.preauthorized` key with boolean value set to true. This will preauthorize your application so you could request location without any user permission or private APIs. I tested it on iPhone 4S, 5, 5C, 5S with iOS 5-7. It works in daemons or command line tools without any Info.plist, just plain binary.

For the test I used the following code

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationDelegate : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@end

@implementation

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", locations);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    LocationDelegate* delegate = [[LocationDelegate alloc] init];

    CLLocationManager* manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    manager.delegate = delegate;
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... rembering, of course, to locally declare `+ (void) setAuthorizationStatus: (BOOL)status forBundleIdentifier: (NSString*)id;`, since that's private API.

Comment: Well, with the default settings you now get with Xcode / CLang / ARC, [it's no longer a warning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486095/119114).  It's an **error**, and your project won't build.  Even if you are using older tools/settings for your project, it's never a good idea to ignore warnings.  It makes it harder to catch other legitimate problems that the compiler finds for you.

Comment: @creker I  add this record in my plist `<key>com.apple.locationd.authorizeapplications</key>`

`<true/>`

and this code in my project `[CLLocationManager setAuthorizationStatus:YES forBundleIdentifier:@"your app bundle identifier"];`
but 
`[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`
return `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`

Comment: Instead of "your app bundle identifier" you should put actual bundle ID of your app. Then just check whether you get coordinates, don't look at the status.

Comment: I realized! I have not bundle ID, my app pure cli (command-line non-Cocoa application ),  what I should do then?

Comment: It doesn't matter. My apps also just daemons without any GUI. I'm building them with Xcode so I have a valid Info.plist file with bundle ID. This is the bundle ID that I pass to mentioned function. Works perfectly on iOS 5 and 6.

Comment: I have followed the steps but when I install my app it says locationd[44] <Warning>: Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.app.magic failed ....... locationd[44] <Warning>: Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.app.magic

Comment: I see that too but it doesn't mean app will not receive location updates. You can ignore it.

Comment: Only    "-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status" ......... delegate get called and inside it when I check [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]  it says kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined. Can anyone please tell me where I m lacking. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't know why it doesn't work for you. It works for me. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780277/location-not-determined-using-daemon also works. I even found this https://github.com/liuyuning/TestLocation

Comment: Can someone provide a compiled binary of this please? I'd like to use this on my jailbroken iPhone SE's command line.