# location not determined using daemon

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, jailbreak

trying to get location using a daemon on ios
looked at this [CLLocationmanager setAuthorizationStatus doesn't work (jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362565/cllocationmanager-setauthorizationstatus-doesnt-work-jailbreak)

but keep getting location not determined
i have entitlements set (checked with ldid)

got an info.plist where the binary is and added the following keys to clients.plist
but still cant get location

```
<key>com.apple.locationd.executable-{binary_path}</key>
 <dict>
 <key>Authorized</key>
 <true/>
 <key>BundleId</key>
 <string>{any_random_bundle}</string>
 <key>Executable</key>
 <string>{binary_path}</string>
 <key>Registered</key>
 <string>{binary_path}</string>
 <key>Whitelisted</key>
 <false/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Check out my update here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086083/get-gps-without-alert-view-with-root-permissionjailbreak

Comment: Thanks, added the entitlement using ldid com.apple.locationd.preauthorized and now getting location.
Do I still need to add to clients.plist and stop and restart locationd or can  I get rid of all that?

Comment: You don't need any of that.

Comment: got rid of all the stop/start locationd and adding to clients.plist, works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Comment by creker worked, simply adding preauthorise entitlement resolved the issue